# How can I send a message in discord using discord.py every minute

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.9

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

client = discord.Client()
channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL-ID)

@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def test():
    await channel.send("test")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    test.start()


TOKEN = "MYTOKEN"


client.run(TOKEN)
```

I got this code from [Sending message every minute in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62569111/sending-message-every-minute-in-discord-py), which says that it should work but I keep on getting the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'test'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Coding/Py/Gmail/bot.py", line 9, in test
    await channel.send("test")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you defined intents?

Comment: @Nurqm no i forgot you had to do that, thanks for the help

Comment: intents shouldn't be the issue, if none are provided it will assume the default ones. Make sure you are passing an integer, not string and do this in on_ready or in the loop itself.

Comment: [Default intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.default) are `presences` and `members` . `Client.get_channel()` is in [guild intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.guilds).

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `None` because the client's cache isn't loaded in yet.

I'd also recommend using `commands.Bot(...)` as opposed to `discord.Client()` if you're planning on adding commands later. `commands.Bot()` inherits `Client()`, so anything you can do right now, you'll also be able to do with `Bot()`.

To fix this, you can get the user in the `on_ready` event:

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def test(channel):
    await channel.send("test")

@bot.event
async def on_ready()
    channel = bot.get_channel(ID_HERE)
    test.start(channel=channel)
```

If you're still getting `None`, you need to enable privileged intents. This can be done by the following code, and enabling the following button in your application page:

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=..., intents=intents)
```

[image]

---

### References:

- [`on_ready()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready)
- [Privileged intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?#privileged-intents)

Comment: what do I put for ID_HERE?

Comment: @TheTroupeMaster The ID of the user that you want to message

Comment: I think he wants to send the message in a channel, so it'll be `bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)`. Sending a message to a user every minute is just spam.

Comment: @Sujit Thanks, just fixed that. Not sure where I got user from haha.