# Selenium data into discord using discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, discord

I made a bot that tracks prices off target.com and I want the prices to go through to discord here is the original code

```
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

OOS = '//*[@id="notifyMe"]'
in_stock = '//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button'

while True:
    web = webdriver.Chrome()

    web.get('https://www.target.com/p/minecraft-bee-pillow-buddy/-/A-79337175')
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        instock_button = web.find_element_by_xpath(in_stock).click()
        print("INSTOCK")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("OOS")
    web.quit()
```

here is what I have tried to get it linked in discord

```
import time
from discord.ext import *
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord_webhooks import DiscordWebhooks
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

in_stock = '//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
while True:
    @bot.command()
    async def weird(ctx):
        channel = client.get_channel(784163508299890738)
        web = webdriver.Chrome()
        web.get('https://www.target.com/p/madden-nfl-20-playstation-4/-/A-54600234')
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            price = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
            for post in price:
                cost = (post.text)

            instock_button = web.find_element_by_xpath(in_stock).click()
            james = ("INSTOCK" + "   PRICE:" + cost)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            marcus = ("OOS" + "   PRICE:" + cost)
        web.quit()
        await channel.send(james)

        client.run("TOKEN")
```

yet when I run this code i get an error

```
raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: 
  The command weird is already an existing command or alias.
```

How do I fix this someone please help!!!!!

Comment: always put full erro message (startin at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: why do you run `command` in `while True` ? You create the same `command` again and again. It doen't run `command` many times. It is not good idea. You could rather run `while True` only with `selenium` in separated thead - and save `prices` in global variable. And `command` should be created only once and it should get `prices` from global variable.

Comment: it would be faster if you create `webdriver` only once - before `while True` - and you don't close it but use it again and again - and close it at the end of program (aftet leaving `while True`)

Comment: [Sending message every minute in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62569111/sending-message-every-minute-in-discord-py) - use `task.loop()` instead of `while True` and `sleep`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `while True` because you create the same command again and again. Besides `discord` has to start own loop with `bot.run()` and it would make problem to run both loops at the same time.

Luckly discord has `task.loop(seconds=...)` to run some code periodically so it may works instead of `while True`. It has to only start it.

I tried to use `on_ready` to start it but it doesn't work on my Linux so I had to use command to manually start it - but later it runs all time

To make it faster I start `Chrome` only once and I close it after stoping bot.

```
import os
import time

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

in_stock_xpath = '//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button'
price_xpath = '//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

#help(tasks.loop)

@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def weird():
    print('[weird] start weird')
    channel = bot.get_channel(784163508299890738)  # `bot`, not `client`

    web.get('https://www.target.com/p/madden-nfl-20-playstation-4/-/A-54600234')
    time.sleep(5)

    try:
        price = web.find_elements_by_xpath(price_xpath)
        for post in price:
            cost = post.text

        instock_button = web.find_element_by_xpath(in_stock_xpath).click()
        message = "INSTOCK   PRICE: " + cost
    except NoSuchElementException:
        cost = '???'
        message = "OOS   PRICE: " + cost

    await channel.send(message)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():   # this doesn't start on my computer
    print('[on_ready] start weird')
    weird.start()

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):  # I start it manually with command `!start`
    print('[start] start weird')
    weird.start()   

# --- main ---

print('start chrome')
web = webdriver.Chrome()  # create only once

print('start bot')
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
bot.run(TOKEN)  # `bot`, not `client`
print('stop bot')

web.quit()  # close only once
print('stop chrome')
```